# Windows 7 doesn't accept product key after cancelling the installation of windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-activation, windows-7-upgrade

I had a licensed version of windows 7( I don't remember which version though) and I was upgrading it to win 10. during the Installation there was an error saying  "system registry contains invalid file paths Installation cannot proceed. This system image was applied without guaranteeing that drive-letter assignments would match across computers." this is okay because I edited environmental variable paths recently.

My problem is when it automatically restored back to windows 7 **ultimate** it is not activated like before and I can't activate it using the product key mentioned in the coa sticker. It says "the product key you have entered will not work with this edition of windows 7". Why is this happening? And how can I activate windows like before.(I want to upgrade this to a activated windows 10 version)

Also I don't have a retail disk because it is an OEM machine I bought from Samsung. (Also I tried calling activation center but my mobile service provider says something like this service is not available for this network or something like that)

Edit: The coa sticker contains the product key for windows 7 home premium. I can't figure out why it restored to ultimate version.

Comment: Had you, or the company you worked for, upgraded to Windows 7 Ultimate?

Comment: So what product is indicated on the sticker? It’s not possible for a specific edition of Windows to turn into another edition. [There is an existing question with a working link to a Windows 7 ISO that can be used to install Retail or OEM copies of Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/872621#872621)